# MapReduce job run as user got permission error on /user/yarn/.staging directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow running a Hive action. The hive action is pretty simple, it just reads from one table copies to another table. The job ran with the following properties:

```
user.name=yarn
mapreduce.job.user.name=cloudfeeds
```

The job fails with the following error:

```
15/07/16 18:45:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1435680786374_0060 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1435680786374_0060 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1435680786374_0060_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://master-1.local:8088/proxy/application_1435680786374_0060/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Permission denied: user=cloudfeeds, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/yarn/.staging":yarn:hdfs:drwx------
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:4387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:835)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
```

I don't understand why user cloudfeeds needs to access the /user/yarn/.staging directory. If the job runs as user cloudfeeds, shouldn't it be trying to access /user/cloudfeeds/.staging instead?

How do I fix this?

thanks,
-shinta

Answer (score 1):

have you validate the core-site.xml, it should be enabled for All User with

```
  <property>
            <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
            <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
            <value>*</value>
    </property>
```

also check hdfs-site.xml what the permission status implies, it should be set as false:

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

The same could help to dig the issue

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to the cloudfeeds user to the staging directory. Any user that executes a yarn application need access to the staging directory. So either set an acl for the group where all these users belong to or blindly give 777 permission.

```
chmod 777 /user/yarn/.staging
```

Comment: That doesnt work, because everytime the job runs, the /user/yarn/.staging directory got back to the broken permission.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below hdfs command,

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /user/yarn/.staging
```

-R means apply to all its sub directories. The above command apply full permission for all users to that directory and all its sub directories.

or if you enabled ACLs, then you can set permission for specific user like below,

```
hadoop fs -setfacl -m -R user:cloudfeeds:rwx /user/yarn/.staging
```

Comment: The chmod did not work as the permission kept going back to 700 whenever our Oozie job ran.

Comment: So you can set ACLs. Refer [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_Access_Control_Lists)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fully understand why, the problem went away when we upgrade from HDP 2.2.4 to HDP 2.2.6. We did not change any of our code or any of our configuration files.